# Will setShape() clear the background of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, transparency

I would like to write a program in java...
I want to set the shape of the window(a JFrame) to a set of PNG Images(with a transparent background).
(Actually, I would like to make the window change its shape continual, and it look like an animation!)
And, I read images from files,save them to a array, then, I use class GeneralPath to get the area of my animated character(in png images), save it to areaArray.

After all things are done, I start the paint thread. It works well...But sometimes the window would flash(ah...I mean a flicker happened, but the background color I saw when flashing is transparent, I could saw my desktop wallpaper!).

I don't want to see the flicker/flash again, would someone help me? Thanks!

P.S. : Sorry for my poor English!

```
  public class JCustomFrame extends JFrame implements Runnable
  {
      private final int max_frame=18;   //Here is the max numbers of my png images
      private BufferedImage[] BufImageArray;    //The array to save all the png images
      private BufferedImage nowImage;   //Save the image to be drawn in this turn
      private int counter;          //Indicate which png image to be drawn
      private Area[] areaArray;     //Save the shapes of the animated character in each png image
      public void run()// a thread function to paint the frame continual
      {
          while(true){
              if(counter==max_frame)counter=0;
              nowImage=BufImageArray[counter];  
              setShape(areaArray[counter]);
              repaint();
              try{
                  Thread.sleep(100);
              }catch(InterruptedException e){
                  System.out.println("Thread.sleep error!");
              }
              counter++;
          }
      }

      public JCustomFrame()
      {
          super();  
          setUndecorated(true);
          setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));    
          counter= 0;
          //...some codes here
          new Thread(this).start();
      }

      public void paint(Graphics graphic)
      {
          graphic.drawImage(nowImage,0,0,this);
      }
  }
```

---

Here is a sample code to run the program:

```
import javax.swing.*;

  public class MainFrame
  {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          JCustomFrame myFrame = new JCustomFrame();
          myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          myFrame.setSize(300,400);
          myFrame.setVisible(true);
          return ;
      }
  }
```

---

I modified 2 lines above, the "png file name" and the "max_frame" to apply the new image files.
I found that if I put the same program on Windows rather than my OpenSuse, it works very well(without the flicker), here I upload all the pack of my source(include the image file).
[Here my code is.](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3VDjcWZZkDqVl9leVAyQkd5d1k)

Thanks again.

==================================================================================

Thanks Andrew Thompson for suggestions.

This time, I try to delete the codes unrelated to the problem, and paste a gif to show the situation. The codes above isn't runnable, but the source code in the link works well.
P.S. The flicker/flash happened in random frame, isn't completely the same as the gif shows.
('cause I could only add a transparent panel in my gif image at a fixed sequence)

Thanks!!

[image: Situation Picture]

Comment: I had edited the original post...add the working code and upload all my file, hope they are useful!!thanks!

Comment: Unrelated but add a call to `super.paint(g);` in your overridden `paint()` method

Comment: I did it before, but...add the super.paint(g); in paint() would make things terrible(it flash much more frequently, I thought it's because the super.paint() would truely clear the all JFrame first, and then draws what you really want.)
So I removed that statement(it doesn't affect the performance so far).

Comment: *"Here my code is."*  Umm.. not too many people will surf off to that link, download 2 source files (and a couple of dozen images) to try and help.  My advice is to post 1 [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that generates the images in a method of the code.  ..as an aside.  `monster1.png` seems to be a ..smiling snowman with a carrot nose.  What kind of *monster* is that?!?  (I must be bored that I checked that image out!)